# Redirect to dashboard after login

Tags: redirect

I use the following code to redirect users on login to dashboard instead of their profile.

It works fine but it also redirects to dashboard when there is `redirect_to=` in url `http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=`

Is possible when there is `redirect_to=` in url to redirect to the appended url and not to dashboard?

```
// Redirect to dashboard on login (instead of profile)
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'app_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
function app_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
        //check for admins
        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            // redirect them to the default place
            return $redirect_to;
        } else {
            return admin_url( 'index.php' );
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second input argument  `$request`, in your `app_login_redirect()` callback function, takes it's value from <sup>[source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/2a76ccac4e07dcc7bac802a3f2e0862221dbe2c1/wp-login.php#L809)</sup>:

```
isset( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ? $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] : '';
```

so if I understand you correctly, you could just check if it's empty or not, if you need to know that within your logic parts.